# RadioButtons android sending data

Tags: java, android, radio-button, radiobuttonlist, radio-group

So i have a question here. I want to implement an activity where there are three radio buttons

rb1

rb2

rb3

And there is a button submit. When any one of those are selected and the button is clicked, it should send an int value to the next activity. For example if rb2 is selected and i click the button submit, it should send int value 10. But if rb3 is selected and `onClick`, it should send 14 to the next Activity.

How to go about it? Here is my current code

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
// Is the button now checked?
boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

// Check which radio button was clicked
switch(view.getId()) {
    case R.id.radio_btn1:
        if (checked)
            // Send value 10 to the next activity
        break;
    case R.id.radio_btn2:
        if (checked)
            // Send value 14 to the next activity
        break;
     }
}
```

Comment: Do you know about `Intents`?

Comment: Yes i know intents

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
// Is the button now checked?
boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

// Check which radio button was clicked
switch(view.getId()) {
    case R.id.radio_btn1:
        if (checked)
            // Send value 10 to the next activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TheActivityYouWantToStart.class);
        intent.putExtra("number", 10);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    case R.id.radio_btn2:
        if (checked)
            // Send value 14 to the next activity
        break;
     }
}
```

To get the number in your next activity you have to get it from the Intent like this

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       int number = getIntent().getIntExtra("number", 999); // 999 is default value
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int valueToBeSent= -1;
switch(view.getId()) {
case R.id.radio_btn1:
    if (checked)
        valueToBeSent = 10;
    break;
case R.id.radio_btn2:
    if (checked)
        valueToBeSent = 14;
    break;
}
if(valueToBeSent!=-1) {
Intent intent = new Intent(_context, NextActivityName.class);
    intent.putExtra("selectedValue", valueToBeSent);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```